# How to use custom images as resources with NativeScript and Angular 2?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm following the tjvantoll tutorial [here](https://tjvantoll.github.io/nativescript-angular-guide/#chapter2.0) about develop an app with NativeScript 1.7 + Angular 2.

I create my images with the [NativeScript Image Builder](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/). My custom image is "**logo_login**" and the default image created by NativeScript is "**icon**". Here is the code:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
var imageSource = require("image-source");

var img = imageSource.fromResource("logo_login");

@Component({
   selector: "myapp",
   template: `
   <StackLayout>
     <Image src="res://icon" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center">  </Image>
     <Button text="Sign in" id="submit-button" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
     <Button text="Sign up"></Button>
   </StackLayout>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["views/login/login-common.css", "views/login/login.css"]
 })
export class AppComponent {
  submit(){
    console.log(img);
  }
}
```

When I run the application, **console.log(img)** return **null** but **src="res://icon"** return the icon image.

So how can I fix the using of custom images while using the NativeScript + Angular?

Comment: Well, you do realize those are two separate resources.  res://icon is not logo_login.     Do you actually have a logo_login.png file the different proper sizes inside your app_resource/android folder/* folders?

Comment: Hi nathanael! res://icon is an example of what is working right now, when i try res://logo_login i see nothing. And yes i have it into app_resource/android folders. I generate it with the official tool (native image builder)

Comment: 1. So are you sure you have a logo_login.png file in _each_ of the drawable-?dpi folders?
2. have you tried "res://logo_login.png" -- I seem to recall one of the two platforms currently needs the .png suffix.  (Fixed in the upcoming 2.0)

Comment: I have also tested your scenario and it works with no problem with logo_login (as Nathanael mentioned - youlogo_login file must be present) - On submit it returns [object Object] as espected and when loaded with res://logo_login it also renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running the : `tns livesync android --emulator --watch`and an issue exit about that here : [livesync synchonize images](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1390)

So just needed to run : `tns run android`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways of how you can load your images dynamically via the Angular 2 and NativeScript

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Injectable } from "angular2/core";

var imageSource = require("image-source");

var imgSrc = imageSource.fromResource("logo_login");

@Component({
  selector: "myapp",
  template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <Image #myImage stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
        <Button text="Change pic" (tap)="submit('res://logo_login')"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

  // similar to getViewById
  @ViewChild("myImage") myImageRef: ElementRef;

  // logo_login.png from App_Resources/Android/drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable-mdpi
  imgNativeSource = 'res://logo_login'; 

  // logo_login.png from local app_folder
  imgAppSource = "~/app_folder/logo_login"

  // angular2 method triggers after view init
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myImageRef.nativeElement.src = "res://icon";
  }

  // custom func with params
  submit(source) {
    this.myImageRef.nativeElement.src = source;

    // this.myImageRef.nativeElement.src = this.imgNativeSource;
  }
}
```

Note that Android says "*A bitmap image. Android supports bitmap files in three formats: .png (preferred), .jpg (acceptable), .gif (discouraged).*" but still the best choice especially for App_resources is to use transperant png files.

Comment: taking imge from local folder works! 
 // logo_login.png from local app_folder
  imgAppSource = "~/app_folder/logo_login"

Comment: And how can I access an mp3 file which is in the `raw` folder ? everyone talks about drawables folders. but what about binary files ? how can I access it? also asked here : https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/folder-location-problem/3304